# Is there a way to write a one line command that randomly samples consecutive rows in a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that provides me with three consecutive lines from a *very* simple dataframe. The real dataframe is extremely long, but here is a simpler one:

```
structure(list(simple = structure(1:5, .Label = c("aa", "bb", 
"cc", "dd", "ee"), class = "factor")), .Names = "simple", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, using `dplyr`:

```
myrandomrows <- sample_n(df, 3)
```

How would I make the sample of rows consecutive?

**Edit:**
I'm hoping to generate the consecutive rows with the data intact, like so:

```
 1     aa
 2     bb
 3     cc
```

Comment: Why not use ``index <- runif(1, 1, nrow(df))`` and ``df[index:(index + 3),]``?

Comment: Thanks Phann, that works very well in that the content also appears. However, a minor problem with that is that the end row of the dataframe also appears when that runs. I'm clearly still getting to grips with syntax- do you know a quick way of stopping that issue? (Removing the comma operator for column did not work)

Comment: I don't see the problem, for me it works the same as Ronaks answer. Is your problem, that there is a line ``Levels: aa bb cc ...``? The reason for it is that you use a ``factor`` variable which is another issue. Or is your problem that your ``data.frame`` is returned as a ``factor`` variable and not as a ``data.frame`` again?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I had completely forgotten that might be an issue. The solution then was to change that column into a character. Problem solved! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `sample` one row and then select next rows to make it consecutive

```
sample(1:nrow(df), 1) + 0:2
```

So, if

```
sample(1:nrow(df), 1) #returns
#[1] 3

sample(1:nrow(df), 1) + 0:2 # would return
#[1] 3 4 5
```

You can subset the dataframe with these indexes.

```
df[sample(1:nrow(df), 1) + 0:2, ]
```

Take care of the edge cases when index values goes beyond row number.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this looks very elegant and works perfectly to generate the consecutive rows. However, I made a mistake in not being absolutely clear: I'm hoping to generate consecutive rows with the content intact, so for example: rows 4-6, "cc" "dd" "ee". I will edit my question to show what I mean.

Comment: @E.O. `df[sample(1:nrow(df), 1) + 0:2, ]` should give you rows with data intact. Or as @Phann suggested use `df[sample(1:(nrow(df)-2), 1) + 0:2, ]` to avoid the edge case.

Comment: @RonakShah this is perfect! Thanks very much to both you and Phann for your help.

Comment: Spoke too soon- I didn't see that there was still the problem of the last line of data being generated. Will keep playing around with `df[sample(1:(nrow(df)-2), 1) + 0:2, ]`

Comment: @E.O. I am not sure, what do you mean by `last line of data being generated` . It works for me.

Comment: @RonakShah Phann pointed out that the problem was that it was being read as a factor. I simply changed it to a character vector and that solved the issue. Thank you for your help!